# How to get binary subexpressions with javaparser

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, javaparser

I am using [javaparser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) to parse the AST for Java source files.

I would like to get all binary subexpressions in the source code as individual nodes.
Here is the source code I am parsing:

```
class MyClass {
  public MyClass() {
    double x = (4 / 10.0) + 15;
  }
}
```

I implemented a Visitor that accepts the built-in BinaryExp type, but the only node that it finds contains the binary expression:

```
(4 / 10.0) + 15
```

Is there a way to visit the subexpression "(4 / 10.0)" as well?
I tried getting the full expression's "left operand", but it is of type Expression, and not BinaryExpr as I expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left operand cannot be of actual type `Expression` because `Expression` is an abstract class.

- You can check the actual type by checking `binEx.getLeft() instanceof BinaryExp`.If this evaluates true, you can cast to BinaryExpression.
- But probably it evaluates false and the node is of type `EnclosedExpr` (parentheses). Then the binary expression is the child of the left node

This will probably not solve the whole problem. I think you missed to apply the visitor to the child nodes. You have to adjust `visit(BinaryExpr n, A arg)`:

- if you use a `GenericVisitorAdaptor` you will have to call `super.visit(n,arg)`
- if you wrote your own adaptor you will have to call `accept(this, arg)` on each child.